# Youtube API Ratings

Tags: youtube-api

I am using YouTube API in one of my projects. In some cases I find that the "gd$rating" is not present in the response I receive . What can be the possible reasons for this ? Is there a work around to get the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a classic example of "don't always trust the API return values to be wholly complete or accurate".  You will most likely have to anticipate this sort of thing happening in your code.  Even if it is defined in the API.

For example: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#youtube_data_api_tag_gd:rating

From the docs: **gd$rating** `This element is only returned if the video has been rated.`